# Add fields dynamically in django ModelForm

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

my model

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    remark = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    data_1 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    data_2 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    data_3 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    data_4 = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Form

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    CHOICES= (("data_1", "data_1"),
               ("data_2", "data_2"),
               ("data_3", "data_3"),
               ("data_4", "data_4"),)
    my_choice = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ["remark"]
```

view

```
class MyView(UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class = MyModelForm
    template_name = "mytemplate.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        selected_choices = self.request.POST.getlist("my_choice")
        for item in selected_choices:
            form.instance.item = False
        form.instance.remarks = form.cleaned_data["remark"]
        form.instance.save()
        return super(MyView, self).form_valid(form)
```

what i want is, i want to take the selected choices  and change its value to False by checking the checkbox and remaining must be unaffected.Please help....

Comment: sorry for that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is hard to understand and doesn't seem to have anything to do with adding fields to forms. But I *think* you are looking for `setattr`:

```
    for item in selected_choices:
        setattr(form.instance, item, False)
```

Comment: plz help sir, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326137/how-to-pass-values-from-models-fields-to-inside-django-annotate-method